# Batch file copies all source files into one destination extensionless file instead of the destination folder

Tags: batch-file, copy, file-extension

I use a post-build script to copy my output DLLs to another folder.

Instead of copying each file separately it would create a file with no extension and put all source files to that file (I check this by hexeditor).

This batch file was working before I reinstall my windows (2008 server). What has happened ?

Comment: You want to try posting the batch file? Otherwise we've nothing to go on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably worked before because the target folder was already there. Try creating the folder first or using the correct xcopy switch